# Introducing just numbers form an interval in a TextField in Java

Tags: java, swing, jformattedtextfield

How can I add just numbers betwwen 0 and 255 in a FormattedTextField in Java?

I tried this way :

```
private JFormattedTextField text4;
//...
text4= new JFormattedTextField(paymentFormat);
    text4.getValue();
    text4.setColumns(3);
    try {
        MaskFormatter mask = new MaskFormatter("###");
        mask.install(text4);
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
       System.out.print("Valoarea nu e corecta");
    }
```

and it doesn`t work...

Comment: Is it possible to be more specific on _"it doesn't work"_?

Comment: IT DISPLAYS : "THE VALUE IS NOT CORRECT" JUST AFTER I COMPILE THE PROGRAM. MOREOVER, THIS SOLUTION COULD WORK FOR EVERY NUMBER BETWEEN 0 AND 999...

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13424140/1076463), and simply adjust the `java.text.Format` to only accept values between 0 and 255

Comment: sorry, Thomas, I forgot the caps lock on:(

Comment: thank you , I solved it with InputVerifier.

Comment: and is there any possibility not to let me type incorrect values(letters) instead of returning an exception if i type a letter?

Answer (score 1):

there are two ways

- use [JSpinner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html) instead of `JFormattedTextField`, to set [proper range in SpinnerNumberModel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7570411/714968)
- add [DocumentFilter to JFormattedTextField](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9430683/714968), and determine if Integer, Double value is less than 0 and more than 255
- [setMinimum / setMaximum for proper XxxFormatter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14876889/714968)
- add [DocumentListener to display overloading for JFormattedTextField](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8582656/714968)